# Objective C: way to check for enabled flags

Tags: objective-c, enums

I am using bitflag to enable/disable some functionality in my code. I have following enum.

```
typedef enum function {
    function1 = 1 << 0,
    function2 = 1 << 1,
    function3 = 1 << 2,
    function4 = 1 << 3
};
```

I know that I need to use following code to check which flag has been enabled.

```
if((flags & function1) == function1)
{
    // do some action
}
```

In my enum, number of flags is large and to check every flag, I need to have that many "if" condition checks. Is there any way which can minimize the number of if statements required? I am new to objective C and looking to implement it in objective C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "large"? 16? 256? 4096? For 256 or less, you could use a table with pointers to functions, but I'd use a normal index (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) instead of bit values.

Comment: To be specific around 32. I need to check for each flag and take appropriate action. I have a single function which checks for every flag. I am receiving bit values from server on which I do not have any control. So I have to move with bit values.

Comment: Then make a for-loop like this: for (i = 0, bit = 1; i < NBITS; i++, bit <<= 1) if (flags & bit) functable[i](); The definition for the table looks a bit weird, but you'll get used to it: void (*functable[])(void) = {fna, fnb, fnc, …, fnz};

Comment: Yeah that's great. It should work. I think calling of function for every flag will add some performance overhead, but good to know this alternative. You should have posted this in answer. I can not accept the comment as answer. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, combine the flags via a bitwise or:

```
if (flags & (function1 | function2 | function3 | function4))
{
  // any of the flags has been set
}
```

Moreover, to check for a particular flag you don't need the part `== function1`, `flags & function1` is sufficient as it will evaluate either to zero or `function1`.

Comment: Yeah. That's correct. But I need to check for each flag separately and just looking for a way to minimize number of if. e.g. to implement it so that i will be able to use switch case.